# Custom Collection Initializers

Tags: c#

Classes that implement `IEnumerable` and provide a `public void Add(/* args */)` function can be initialized like in the following example:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
```

which calls the `Add(int)` function 3x after initializing the `List<int>`.

Is there a way to define this behavior explicitly for my own classes? For example, could I have the initializer call a function other than the appropriate `Add()` overload?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

No, the compiler requires a method named `Add` for the collection initializer to work. This is defined in C# specification and cannot be changed:

> #### C# Language Specification - 7.5.10.3 Collection Initializers
>
> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable` or a compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the collection initializer invokes an `Add` method on the target object with the expression list of the element initializer as argument list, applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, ***the collection object must contain an applicable `Add` method*** for each element initializer. *[emphasis mine]*

Of course, the `Add` method can take more than one argument (like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`):

```
dic = new Dictionary<int, int> { 
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4 }
};
// translated to:
dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dic.Add(1, 2);
dic.Add(3, 4);
```

Comment: I could have sworn that it had to be a public method too - but it looks like I'm wrong. Now I'll have to fix the bit of C# in Depth I was reviewing today :(

Comment: @JonSkeet, it looks like compilation fails if the `Add` method isn't visible at the location where the initializer syntax is used.

Comment: @kpozin: Exactly - hopefully I *did* get round to fixing this before I shipped C# in Depth :)

Comment: VB.NET gets to use extension methods for `Add()` on initializers. :/

Answer (score 4):

Adding just as a sample answer of what works. AFAIK, only Add will work. Code snippet taken from [Marius Schulz](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/06/26/fun-with-custom-c-collection-initializers)

```
// simple struct which represents a point in three-dimensional space
public struct Point3D
{
    public readonly double X;
    public readonly double Y;
    public readonly double Z;

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}

// implementation of a collection of points, which respects
// the compiler convention for collection initializers and
// therefore both implements IEnumerable<T> and provides
// a public Add method
public class Points : IEnumerable<Point3D>
{
    private readonly List<Point3D> _points;

    public Points()
    {
        _points = new List<Point3D>();
    }

    public void Add(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        _points.Add(new Point3D(x, y, z));
    }

    public IEnumerator<Point3D> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _points.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}

// instantiate the Points class and fill it with values like this:
var cube = new Points
{
    { -1, -1, -1 },
    { -1, -1,  1 },
    { -1,  1, -1 },
    { -1,  1,  1 },
    {  1, -1, -1 },
    {  1, -1,  1 },
    {  1,  1, -1 },
    {  1,  1,  1 }
};
```