# Array like initialization class C#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

might be stupid question, but I would like to initialize my array of objects like this:

```
FooBar[] fooBars = new FooBars[]
{
    {"Foo", "Bar"},
    {"Foo", "Bar"}
};
```

where FooBar is:

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string foo;
    public string bar;
}
```

I've tried inherit from CollectionBase and add Add(string) method, or string[] operator, but none of those works :/

Comment: Ofc dictionaries work like that:

    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"foo", "bar"}};

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83h9yskw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you have decalred an array of FooBars, then you also need to populate it with instances of FooBars, so you would have to do `new Foobar()`, and then fill in the `foo` and `bar` properties. However a better way would be to pass those in the FooBar constructor. Additionally if you want to use a string pair, consider using a dictionary.

Comment: If think you are missing an inheritance from IEnumerable - see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9570300/1632576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat a bit by giving class FooBar an implicit constructor (requires latest version of C# for the tuple support):

```
public class FooBar
{
    public string foo;
    public string bar;

    public static implicit operator FooBar((string, string) init)
    {
        return new FooBar{ foo = init.Item1, bar = init.Item2 };
    }
}
```

Then code like this will work:

```
var fooBars = new FooBar[]
{
    ("Foo1", "Bar1"),
    ("Foo2", "Bar2")
};
```

OR

```
FooBar[] fooBars = 
{
    ("Foo1", "Bar1"),
    ("Foo2", "Bar2")
};
```

And then:

```
foreach (var fooBar in fooBars)
    Console.WriteLine($"foo = {fooBar.foo}, bar = {fooBar.bar} ");
```

which seems fairly close to what you're aiming for (albeit with parentheses instead of braces).

But normally you'd just use the `new FooBar("Foo", "Bar")` syntax as per the other answer.

Comment: This helps a lot, not exacly what I was looking for, but looks cool ;)

Comment: @blackmaciek Please be aware that it's not a very efficient solution, since you will be constructing a temporary tuple for each call to the `FooBar` constructor, which would NOT be necessary if you use the normal `new Foobar(...)` syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are looking for?
I don't understand exactly what you're asking.

You can play a bit with it in this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KjI0Nz) if you want to.

```
public class FooBar
{
    public FooBar(string foo, string bar)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public string foo;
    public string bar;
}

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    FooBar[] fooBars = new FooBar[] {
        new FooBar("Foo", "Bar"), 
        new FooBar("Foo", "Bar")
    };
}
```