# Implementing a collection initializer for my List wrapper in C#

Tags: c#

I've created a class which wraps a List:

```
class Wrapper
{
    private List<int> _list
}
```

I would like to be able to initialize a new Wrapper object like this:

```
new Wrapper() {1, 2, 3};
```

That's supposed to initialize the Wrapper's `_list` to a list containing {1, 2, 3}.

What do I need to add to the class code in order to enable the functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495791/custom-collection-initializers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two things:

- You need to implement `IEnumerable` (although its behaviour is unimportant for the sake of the collection initializer itself). You don't have to implement the generic version, but you'd *normally* want to.
- You need an `Add` method accepting the element type as a parameter (`int` in this case)

So the compiler will then transform this:

```
Wrapper x = new Wrapper() {1, 2, 3};
```

Into this:

```
Wrapper tmp = new Wrapper();
tmp.Add(1);
tmp.Add(2);
tmp.Add(3);
Wrapper wrapper = tmp;
```

The simplest approach would almost certainly be to delegate to your list:

```
class Wrapper : IEnumerable<int>
{
    private readonly List<int> _list = new List<int>();

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    // Explicit implementation of non-generic interface
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(int item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }
}
```

If you want to make your wrapper slightly more efficient to iterate over, you *could* change the `GetEnumerator` methods to include a public one returning `List<T>.Enumerator`:

```
// Public method returning a mutable struct for efficiency
public List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return _list.GetEnumerator();
}

// Explicit implementation of non-generic interface
IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}

// Explicit implementation of non-generic interface
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: "If you want to make your wrapper slightly more efficient to iterate over, you could change the GetEnumerator methods to include a public one returning List<T>.Enumerator:" -- Or, define a custom local `struct Enumerator` containing a single field of type `List<int>.Enumerator`, and wrap its methods. It behaves the same, but that IMO makes more sense for the caller, if the caller has a reason to name the enumerator type (as you've done here for `List<T>`).

Answer (score 2):

```
class ListWrapper :IEnumerable<int>
{
    private List<int> _list = new List<int>();

    public void Add(int i)
    {
        _list.Add(i);
    }

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```