# Initializer syntax: new ViewDataDictionary { { "Name", "Value" } }

Tags: c#, initialization, c#-3.0

I was searching for a way to pass ViewDataDictionary to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC that I came to this syntax:

```
new ViewDataDictionary { { "Name", "Value" } }
```

I'm a bit confused about the initializer syntax here. can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: MSDN on collection initializers in [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) and [VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`ViewDataDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) implements `IDictionary<string, object>`.

`IDictionary<string, object>` is essentially a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

Your `ViewDataDictionary` initializer (outer curly braces) contains another set of curly braces that represents a `KeyValuePair<string, object>` initializer.

The reason this is possible is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495801/490282).

You can `Add` multiple items by comma separating the `KeyValuePair<string, object>` initializers:

```
var data = new ViewDataDictionary 
{ 
    { "Name", "Value" }, 
    { "Name2", "Value2" } 
};
```

Is the same as:

```
var data = new ViewDataDictionary 
{ 
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Name", "Value"), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Name2", "Value2") 
};
```

Essentially, the inner curly braces are nice syntax for initializing `KeyValuePair<string, object>` objects.

Comment: Are items in `IDictionary<string, object>` of type `KeyValuePair<string, object>`?

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs yes, `IDictionary<string, object>` is essentially a collection of `KeyValuePair<string, object>`.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this using an extension method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Use this extension method to create a dictionary or objects
///     keyed by their property name from a given container object
/// </summary>
/// <param name="o">Anonymous name value pair object</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object o)
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var propertyInfo in o.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
        {
            dictionary.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.GetValue(o, null));
        }
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

And an Html Helper extension:

```
/// <summary>
/// When viewData is null, we just return null.  Otherwise, we
///     convert the viewData collection to a ViewDataDictionary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="htmlHelper">HtmlHelper provided by view</param>
/// <param name="viewData">Anonymous view data object</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static ViewDataDictionary vd(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object viewData)
{
    if (viewData == null) return null;

    IDictionary<string, object> dict = viewData.ToDictionary();

    //We build the ViewDataDictionary from scratch, because the
    //  object parameter constructor for ViewDataDictionary doesn't
    //  seem to work...
    ViewDataDictionary vd = new ViewDataDictionary();
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        vd[item.Key] = item.Value;
    }

    return vd;
}
```

Use from a razor file as:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Some/Path.cshtml", Model, Html.vd(new { SomeKey = SomeObj }))
```