# Is there a {} Operator?

Tags: c#, list

You can use

```
List<string> sList = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
```

to create a new List and add 2 items. The `{ "1", "2" }`-part only works because `List<T>` has implemented a `Add()` method.

my question: is `{}` something like a operator and can it be overloaded e.g. to add items twice

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: its not an operator. here is the list of operators https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "to add items twice"?

Comment: @JonSkeet the result would be `1,1,2,2` - but that's just a example. i want to know if i can get between the `{}` and the `Add()`

Comment: And the answer is "no, but you can provide your own Add method" - depending on the class involved, of course.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is {} something like a operator and can it be overloaded e.g. to add
>   items twice

Any collection type which provides an `Add` method, built in or as an extension method ([starting from C#-6](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6)), can use the collection initializer provided by the `{ }` syntax. If your `Add` method adds the same item twice to that collection, then that is what it will do.

If you'd want the behavior of `{ }` to change, you'd have to override or overload the `Add` method on the collection.

Some additional specification goodness (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2495801/1870803)):

> ### C# Language Specification - 7.5.10.3 Collection Initializers
>
> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied
>   must be of a type that implements System.Collections.IEnumerable or a
>   compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the
>   collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object with
>   the expression list of the element initializer as argument list,
>   applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, the
>   collection object must contain an applicable Add method for each
>   element initializer.

Comment: Or overload it. Or (as of C# 6) add an extension method.

Comment: @JonSkeet As of C#6, does it still need to implement `IEnumerable`? I only ask because [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) says "*...when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable or a class with an Add extension method*"

Comment: Adding a `Add` method has been available for a while as an extension method, hasn't it been?

Comment: @Rawling: Yes, it does. That's a documentation bug :(

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: Add extension methods weren't usable *for colleciton initializers* before C# 6, AFAIK...

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, just looked that up. It was VB.NET that had it for a while.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough. I hoped they'd dropped it, I never liked that restriction.