# Using collection initializer on my own class

Tags: c#, msdn, collection-initializer

I am trying to add collection initializing to my class. I read about the initializers here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx#Anchor_2

I'll quote the important part that puzzles me:

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection class that implements IEnumerable or a class with an **Add** extension method.

Ok, so I want to emphasize on the word **or**. As I read it, I should be able to make a class with an **Add** method, and then the collection initializer should work on this class? This doesn't seem to be the case. One thing I did note, was that it does in fact say an Add extension method. So I tried creating the Add as an extension method as well, but to no avail.

Here's a small sample I tried that does not work:

```
public class PropertySpecificationCollection
{
    private List<PropertySpecification> _internalArr;
    public void Add(PropertySpecification item)
    {
        _internalArr.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Is the quote subject to other interpretations than mine? I tried reading it over and over again, to see if I could interpret it in any other way, but failed to do so.

So I guess my question is: Am I interpreting it wrong, am I missing something, or is there an error in the description of collection initializers on MSDN?

Comment: What happens when you create an instance of `PropertySpecificationCollection` and initialize the collection in the constructor?

Comment: This looks like an error in the documentation, you have to implement `IEnumerable` and there must be a suitable `Add` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495791/custom-collection-initializers

Comment: @miparnisari I get a compiler error: Cannot initialize type 'PropertySpecificationCollection' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. Which confirms what others are saying, that it needs to implement IEnumerable

Comment: @Mino I did look at that question before I asked this one. But since there was no link to source of the answer provided there - and I was looking at official documentation on MSDN that said something different - I asked this question to make sure which one was right and which was wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be "and", not "or".

Collection initializers are described in [C# language specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx), section 7.6.10.3 Collection initializers:

> The collection object to which a collection initializer is applied must be of a type that implements System.Collections.IEnumerable or a compile-time error occurs. For each specified element in order, the collection initializer invokes an Add method on the target object with the expression list of the element initializer as argument list, applying normal overload resolution for each invocation. Thus, the collection object must contain an applicable Add method for each element initializer.

It clearly states that the collection must implement `IEnumerable` **and** there needs to be an `Add` method. The call to the `Add` method is resolved using normal overload resolution process, so it can be an extension method, generic method etc.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a link to the section of the C# language specification in addition to the quote?

Comment: @Inrego It's only available as a .docx. I linked the download site.