# C# List definition, parentheses vs curly braces

Tags: c#, list

I've just noticed that when you declare a `List` in c# you can put parentheses or curly braces at the end.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>{};
```

Both these list appear to have the same functionality. Is there any actual difference caused by declaring them with parentheses or curly braces?

Comment: In addition to all answers, and to be clear, note that both lines will compile to the same IL, so there is really no functional difference. Use the first version when you don't need the collection initializer (curly braces).

Comment: @PatriceGahide, good to know that it will compile the same either way. I asked in case there was some subtle difference that might cause issues one day.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The use of curly braces `{ }` is called a *collection initializer*.  For types that implement `IEnumerable` the `Add` method would be invoked normally, on your behalf:

```
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
```

Empty collection initializers are allowed:

```
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>() { };
```

And, when implementing an initializer, you may omit the parenthesis `()` for the default constructor:

```
List<string> myList2 = new List<string> { };
```

You can do something similar for class properties, but then it's called an *object initializer*.

```
var person = new Person
                 {
                     Name = "Alice",
                     Age = 25
                 };
```

And its possible to combine these:

```
var people = new List<Person>
                 {
                     new Person
                         {
                             Name = "Alice",
                             Age = 25
                         },
                     new Person
                         {
                             Name = "Bob"
                         }
                 };
```

This language feature introduced in C# 3.0 also supports initializing [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), which is especially useful in LINQ query expressions:

```
var person = new { Name = "Alice" };
```

They also work with arrays, but you can further omit the type which is inferred from the first element:

```
var myArray = new [] { "one", "two", "three" };
```

And initializing multi-dimensional arrays goes something like this:

```
var myArray = new string [,] { { "a1", "b1" }, { "a2", "b2" }, ... };
```

**Update**

Since C# 6.0, you can also use an *index initializer*. Here's an example of that:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
                       {
                           ["one"] = 1,
                           ["two"] = 2,
                           ["three"] = 3
                       };
```

Comment: You meant `ICollection`, no? You can't `Add` items to an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: No, I meant classes that implement IEnumerable. The collection initializer would look for an `Add` method following normal overload resolution. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2495801/2707705).

Comment: Summary: It's just a language feature ;).

Comment: Wow, didn't know you can omit the array constructor like that!

Comment: It’s weird syntax to not using [] for arrays.

Answer (score 7):

They have different semantics.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

The above line initializes a new List of Strings, and the `()` is part of the syntax of building a new object by calling its constructor with no parameters.

```
List<string> myList2 = new List<string>{};
```

The above line initializes a new List of Strings with the elements presented inside the `{}`. So, if you did `List<string> myList2 = new List<string>{"elem1", "elem2"};` you are defining a new list with 2 elements. As you defined no elements inside the `{}`, it will create an empty list.

#### But why does the second line have no `()` ?

That makes part of a discussion in which omitting the parenthesis in this case represents a call to the default constructor. Take a look at [This Link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/20/ambiguous-optional-parentheses-part-one/)

Answer (score 5):

The first version initialises an empty list.  The second version is used to initialise the list with values.  You wouldn't, or shouldn't, see the second version used without at least one instance of `T`.

So you could do something like:

```
List<string> Foo = new List<string>{"foo", "bar"};
```

or

```
List<T> Foo = new List<T>{SomeInstancesOfT};
```

This is useful in many places when initialising objects.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To be short - there is no difference in the objects created.

But there's more:
What you are asking isn't a `List` specific question - it's a question of `object` and `Collection` initialization.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Comment: Why not summarise the explanation at the end of that link in your answer? Saves everyone a click, avoids the issue of link rot and makes your answer more useful.