# Difference with/without parentheses in list declaration

Tags: c#, list

I wonder if there is a difference between writing list declare with or without parentheses.

I tested both :

```
List<int> ListWithParentheses = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> ListWithoutParentheses = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

And I got the sames results.

Comment: There is none..

Comment: No difference... They are the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548446/c-sharp-list-definition-parentheses-vs-curly-braces Just refer this one.. I think it will be helpful

Comment: Dublicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548446/c-sharp-list-definition-parentheses-vs-curly-braces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use parameters, as in

```
List<int> ListWithParentheses = new List<int>(capacity: 100) { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and then you absolutely need the `()`. When you have 0 parameters, you can use `()` or by a special rule omit them all together.

Comment: Should be the answer. \+Info : You can define capacity or adding a whole IEnumerable on the parameter